# Flask не видит css

Tags: css, flask, static

```
    /Project
        - app.py
        /main
            /templates
                -index.html
            /static
                -style.css
            -main.py
```

Структура проекта такая.

```
# main.py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

new = Blueprint('new', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')


@new.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from main.main import new

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='main/static')

app.register_blueprint(new)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Так подключаю css.

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "../static/style.css">
```

Проблема заключается в том что если из файла **app.py** убрать пути к папкам **templates** и **static** то он отказывается воспринимать **css**, а я хочу сделать еще несколько директорий как **main**, где будут такие же **static** и **templates**.
Сам шаблон он видит, потому что через настройки самого Pycharm назначил папку для **templates**.

Еще не очень понимаю почему я вообще должен указывать полный путь к файлу **css**, если я уже указал ему на папку **static**.

Comment: Во-первых, если вы не указали `static_url_path`, то значит он в main.py и app.py одинаковый по умолчанию `static_url_path='/static'` и они конфликтуют друг с другом. Во-вторых, не забывайте, что путь относительных ссылок ищется относительно текущего адреса в адресной строке, а не относительно папок на сервере, ведь браузер ничего не знает ни про какие папки на сервере и он не знает ни про какой templates, он знает только про адрес в адресной строке. А когда у вас открыта главная страница, то использование `href= "../` не имеет смысла, ведь над главной страницей нет никакой родительской папки

Comment: Информация годная, но я все еще не понял как решить проблему))